# How to make a new checkbox appear on clicking button in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, visibility

How can I create a new checkbox every time I click a button and how do I hide a check box?

Also, why doesn't `checkbox.setVisibility(View.Gone);` work the same way `textview.setVisibility(View.Gone)` worked?

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout my_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
button.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
     void onClick(){
          CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
          checkBox.setText(Str_Array[i]);
          my_layout.addView(checkBox);
    }
});
```

Comment: what does hiding the check box means? does u want the space for checkbox and just make invisible(use Visibility.INVISIBLE) or if u don't need to give space to checkbox(use Visibility.GONE)...whereas GONE works fine for checkbox also..but as u set i need to recheck too...i would suggest u to try INVISIBLE for recheck...

Answer (score 0):

Create the checkbox in the layout and set visibility to `View.GONE`, and when you need set visibility to `View.VISIBLE` to show the checkbox

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)