# Add checkboxes on click

Tags: android, checkbox, onclick

I have an image file on which if clicked anywhere I would like X'd checkboxes to show up. (Right now its set up as check marks). The code that I have is just for connecting page 1 to page 2 with a button click. Here it is

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        public static Button button1;
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnclickButtonListener();
    }
    public void OnclickButtonListener() {
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextpage);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText userTextEntry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.BRinfo);
                String userdata = userTextEntry.getText().toString();
                int userNumber = Integer.parseInt(userdata);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Page2.class);
                intent.putExtra("para name",userNumber);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }}
```

Part of the XML code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="vt.tacticalcombat.MainActivity"
    android:clickable="true">



<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@mipmap/combat2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText17"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/last4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/last4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView" />



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:id="@+id/nextpage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/otherinfo"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/otherinfo"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox28"
        android:checked="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rarmtypeinfo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mvc"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mvc" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox28"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/injury"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/injury"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/larmtype"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox28"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/checkBox28" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454531/how-to-make-a-new-checkbox-appear-on-clicking-button-in-android)! but it did not work. How can I do this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you want to make your `CheckBox` visible on a click event on your `ImageView` ?

Comment: @PrerakSola Yes. Currently I do not have any checkboxes on the image.

Comment: I do not understand the statement **checkboxes on image**.

Comment: @PrerakSola The image is an area which when clicked will be marked by an X. Multiple clicks, multiple X's. But if overlapped, the X goes away. Sorry, if I am not clear.